# Drizzle React Component ContractData returns empty

Tags: contract-development, truffle-contract, drizzle

My contract call to a simple view function that returns an array of data returns empty using:
From testing it appears that ContractData can't deal with more than one return value. If I return one unit then it works, but more than that ... broken.

```
<ContractData
  contract="TheContract"
  method="getData"
  methodArgs={[accounts[0], 0, { from: accounts[0] }]}
/>
```

Using Remix or even web3 works perfect, with the above I only get react-text place holders, no data.

Worth noting: I also make use of ContractForm and that only reloads the page 3 times and does not send a transaction to my contract.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Using quotes sorts the problem out for a contract view function that returns a single element

<ContractData
  contract="TheContract"
  method="getData"
  methodArgs={[accounts[0], "0", { from: accounts[0] }]}
/>